# Why am I receiving this Run time exception?

Tags: java, arrays, interface

I am working on a program that will add random numbers to an array until it puts a duplicate number in the array and then it should print how many numbers were generated before the duplicate number was generated.

When I run the program I receive this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at arrayintlog.TestLuck.main(TestLuck.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - arrayintlog.ArrayIntLog is not abstract and does not override abstract method contains(java.lang.String) in arrayintlog.IntLogInterface
    at arrayintlog.ArrayIntLog.<clinit>(ArrayIntLog.java:6)
    ... 1 more
Java Result: 1
```

I have no clue what this exception means. I've only ever done one interface before and that was almost exactly the same but with a string array and I had no issues with it.

With this one netbeans keeps telling me to add abstract to my ArrayIntLog class, but if I do that my ArrayIntLog constructor does not work in my main class?

What am I doing wrong/missing with this?

Here is my main class

```
package arrayintlog;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestLuck 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int cycles = 0;
        String name;
        int min = 1;
        int max = 10000;
        int duplicate;

        Random rand = new Random();
        int random = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the name of your Log: ");
        name = in.next();


        ArrayIntLog myLog = new ArrayIntLog(name);

        for (int index = 0; index <= myLog.size(); index++)
        {
            myLog.insert(12);
            int duplicateCheck = log[index];

            if (myLog.contains(duplicateCheck))
            {
                myLog.toString();
                System.out.println("It took " + cycles + " cycles to generate duplicate numbers randomly.");
            }
            else
            {
                cycles++;
            }
        }       

    }

}
```

Here is my array int log class:

```
package arrayintlog;


public class ArrayIntLog implements IntLogInterface
{
    protected String name; //name of the IntLog
    protected int[] log; //array that holds the integers
    protected int lastIndex = -1;

    //==========================Constructor=====================================
    public ArrayIntLog(String name, int maxSize)
    {
        log = new int[maxSize];
        this.name = name;
    }

    //==========================Constructor=====================================
    public ArrayIntLog(String name)
    {
        log = new int[100];
        this.name = name;
    }

    //===========================Insert=========================================
    public void insert(int element) 
    {
        lastIndex++;
        log[lastIndex] = element;
    }

    //===========================isFull=========================================
    public boolean isFull() 
    {
        if(lastIndex == (log.length - 1))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //============================Size==========================================
    public int size() 
    {
        return lastIndex + 1;
    }

    //===========================Contains=======================================
    public boolean contains(int element) 
    {
        int location = 0;
        while (location <= lastIndex)
        {
            if (element == (log[location]))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                location++;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //=============================Clear========================================
    public void clear() 
    {
        for (int index = 0; index <= lastIndex; index++)
        {
            log[index] = null;
        }
        lastIndex = -1;
    }

    //=============================getName======================================
    public String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String logString = "Log " + name +"/n/n";

        for (int index = 0; index <= lastIndex; index++)
        {
            logString = logString + (index+1) + ". " +
                    log[index] + "/n";
        }
        return logString;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `IntLogInterface` interface (which you didn't post) contains at least another method (`contains(String)`) which you haven't implemented in your `ArrayIntLog` class.

Your IDE keeps telling you to add the `abstract` keyword to your `ArrayIntLog` class because a class must either implement all `abstract` methods inherited or defined by implemented interfaces, or the class itself must be declared `abstract` and leave implementing the "missing" methods for subclasses.

Obviously until the "missing" methods are not implemented, the class cannot be instantiated hence you can't instantiate `ArrayIntLog` if it is `abstract`.

Simply implement all methods defined by `IntLogInterface`.

Comment: ok, I must of accidently made my contains method String instead of int in my interface. I appreciate the full explanation. sorry i didn't post the interface to begin with. I thought for sure that couldn't contain the issue...live and learn

Answer (score 0):

You should implement all functions of IntLogInterface Interface

Answer (score 0):

The exception is self-explanatory. You have to implement `contains(String element)` in `ArrayIntLog` class. When you are implementing an `interface`, you need to implement all the methods in that interface.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement all the abstract methods in `IntLogInterface`.

It says that "arrayintlog.ArrayIntLog is not abstract and does not override abstract method `contains(java.lang.String)` ". But your implemented `contains` method has different signature: `public boolean contains(int element)`

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory.

```
    arrayintlog.ArrayIntLog is not abstract and does not override abstract method contains(java.lang.String) in arrayintlog.IntLogInterface
```

If you are using an interface, don't forget to implement all of it's methods.
Do that and you are good to go.